# How to determine limits of a semi-infinite volume of a cone?

Tags: integration, volume

I'm struggling to find the limits need for this equation to give me the answer the question requires.
$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $x>=0$ for the integral $\int\int\int(xe^{-z}) dV$.

I've got that z is between 0 and infinity and theta between 0 and $\pi$ and R between 0 and z but when that is integrated i can't get 4, which is what the question requires the answer to be.

Can anyone tell me where i've gone wrong?

Comment: $x \geq 0$ would mean $-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

Comment: Which is exactly the cone? Is $z\ge 0$? Do we have $z\ge \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or $0\le z\le  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? (Only one of them leads to a convergent integral.) Which is the source of the problem? What is the answer you've got - the one that is not four, and how did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

try limits of r bounded by z and 0. limits of z bounded by zero and infinity. And your limit for theta should be between pi/2 and -pi/2. The limit for theta is because the cone is between the posotive y-axis and the negative y-axis. so theta is pi/2 at the posotive y-axis and theta is negative pi/2 when it goes anti-clockwise from the posotive x-axis.